# How to get the highest z-index value of several div have same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select DIV with highest z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005688/select-div-with-highest-z-index)

How to get the highest z-index value?
put the all div z-index value into array and use math.max? or any suggestion?

```
<div class="a" z-index="1">
<div class="a" z-index="3">
<div class="a" z-index="4">
<div class="a" z-index="5">
<div class="a" z-index="6">
<div class="a" z-index="11">...

<div class="b" z-index="//top+1">
```

js

```
var top = // highest z-index value;
```

Comment: put the all div z-index value into array and use `math.max` :P, that'd be fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var maxValue = Math.max.apply( Math, $('.a').map(function() {
    return +$.attr(this, 'z-index');
}));
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFhzu/

---

If you're using modern JavaScript, you don't need that fancy `apply`. You can spread the values instead:

```js
let maxValue = Math.max(...$('.a').get().map(el => +$.attr(el, 'z-index')));
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7y3sxgbk/

Comment: can you please explain the code?

Comment: The [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function takes a function that will be called for each element in the jQuery collection, returning a new array with all the values that were returned by the function. The [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function lets you pass a bunch of arguments to the underlying function as an array instead.

Answer (score 3):

you could do:

```
var zIndx = [];
$("div.a").each(function() {
    zIndx.push( $(this).attr("z-index") );
});
console.log( Math.max.apply( Math, zIndx ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's `Array.reduce` can do the job.  `.get` can get you the array you need:

```
var top = $(".a").get().reduce(function (a, b) {
   return Math.max(typeof a === 'object' && $(a).attr('z-index') || a,
      $(b).attr('z-index'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8jpea/1/

By the way, be careful about using your own self-defined attributes.  Go with `data-z-index` if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function you can use.

```
var index_highest = 0;   

// more effective to have a class for the div you want to search and 
// pass that to your selector

$(".a").each(function() {

         // always use a radix when using parseInt

         var index_current = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"), 10);

         if(index_current > index_highest) {
               index_highest = index_current;
          }
});

console.log(index_highest);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var top = 0;
    $('.a').each(function(){
        if(top < parseInt($(this).attr('z-index'))){
            top= parseInt($(this).attr('z-index'));
        }
    });
    $('.b').attr('z-index',top+1);
```

[jsfiddle.net/EC36x](http://jsfiddle.net/EC36x/)